# Javascript .click() callback function apparently not called in Bootstrap accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-material-design

I'm working on updating a static website at www.peek.solutions which contains a [Bootstrap accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example). I'm working on a branch (at https://github.com/khpeek/peek-solutions/tree/accordion-chevrons) in which I'm trying to add up/down-pointing chevrons to each list item which toggle according to whether it is expanded or not. I'm using Material Design icons (cf. https://materialdesignicons.com/bootstrap).

As a first stab at a solution, I'm trying to see whether I can even change the appearance of one icon. I've tried to illustrate it in a snippet below, but unfortunately, the icons don't render unless you download the fonts (as can be done by running `npm install` in the linked repository).

But basically, it seems that the problem is that the callback function of `$('#accordion button).click()` is not being called since if I set a `debugger;` trace in the body of that function, it does not pause in my browser.

Any ideas why this function is not getting called?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion button").click(function(){
        $("#accordion button .mdi").removeClass("mdi-chevron-up");
        $("#accordion button .mdi").removeClass("mdi-chevron-down");
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
 
 
   <div id="accordion">

 <div class="card border-bottom-0">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-light w-100 text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-up float-right"></i>
            <span>Pipeline Integrity Assessment and Design</span>
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Our services include the design and assessment of subsea pipelines for lateral and/or upheaval buckling, arctic pipelines subject to ice gouging, stamukha loadings and/or thaw settlements, and pipelines crossing active faults, as well as more routine design and assessment.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Update**

It seems from experimenting in the console that calling [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) on the material icon does not remove its class:

[image]

As you can see, it still as the `'mdi-chevron-up'` class even after I've tried to remove it. Could this be the reason the icon is not changing?

Comment: Use `on()` to set event listeners.

Comment: the function seem to be called just fine in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sz6r38wv/3/ ( check the console when clicking ) and using `toggleClass()` changed the icon,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on('click',function(){});` :http://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion button").on('click',function(){
        $("#accordion button .mdi").removeClass("mdi-chevron-up");
        $("#accordion button .mdi").removeClass("mdi-chevron-down");
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
 
 
   <div id="accordion">

 <div class="card border-bottom-0">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-light w-100 text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-up float-right"></i>
            <span>Pipeline Integrity Assessment and Design</span>
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Our services include the design and assessment of subsea pipelines for lateral and/or upheaval buckling, arctic pipelines subject to ice gouging, stamukha loadings and/or thaw settlements, and pipelines crossing active faults, as well as more routine design and assessment.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: as I see in console when I run it that classes removed